# How to fix this form. Error in import data?

Tags: php, forms, submit

I am setting up a landing page with an Email or phone number field and I am not sure why I am not getting the information supplied.

Running server with PHP 7.2.18.
I have tried changing the button for an input (which submits) and changing type="text" for type="email"

IN THE HTML FILE

```
<form class="form-mini" method="post" name="contactform" action="send_form_email.php">
    <div class="form-row">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Your email address or phone number">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Explain me how this works</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

IN THE PHP FILE

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];

$formcontent="From: Nombre \n Message: Mensaje";
$recipient = "myemailaddress@here.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "$email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

I would like to receivr an email with the email or phone number from the submitter at myemailaddress@here.com

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error message you get?

Comment: Are you getting an email with the form data missing or is it simply not sending an email at all?

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed No error message, actually the form leads me to the echo Thank you page.

Comment: @kainaw I am simply not getting the email :( I don't know how to check if it's been sent

Comment: The PHP mail function cannot send mail by itself. It requires the server to have sendmail functionality. Make sure your server is set up properly: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.setup.php